# What may cause losing object at the other end of a pointer in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

EDIT:  I have found the error: I did not initialize an array with a size. question can be closed.

---

I have a class `V`, and another class `N`. An object of `N` will have an array of pointers to objects of class `V` (say `V **vList`). So, `N` has a function like 
`V **getList();`
Now in some function of other classes or simply a driver function, if I say `V **theList = (N)n.getList();` Q1: `theList` would be pointing at the 1st element of the array? Given that the size of array is known, can I loop through with index `i` and say `V *oneV = *vList[i]`? Please correct me if what I'm doing above is wrong.

---

I have been using debugger to trace through the whole process of my program running, the thing I found was that after using `V *oneV = vList[i]`, the value of the pointers in the array, `vList`, were the same as when they were created, but if I follow the pointer to where it is pointing at, the object was gone. I'm guessing that might be the reason why I am getting seg fault or bus error. Could it be the case? WHY did I 'loose' the object at the other end of a pointer? What did I do wrong?

---

and yes, I am working on a school assignment, that's why I do not want to print out my codes, I want to finish it myself, but I need help finding a problem. I think I still need explanation on array of pointers. Thank you

Comment: You should add another left-quote before "V *oneV = *vList[i]".  The text is a little confused at this time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q1 is right. For the second part, `V *oneV = vList[i]` would be the correct syntax. In your syntax you are dereferencing one more time (treating an object of type `V` as a pointer to such an object) which obviously is crashing your code.

EDIT:
Since you are using the correct syntax, the reason of segfaults would depend on your memory management of the objects of type `V`. If you have inserted addresses of objects created on the stack (automatic vars, not by `new` or `malloc`) inside a function and are trying to access them outside of it, then the pointers would be dangling and your code will crash.

Comment: oops, it is a typo, sorry. I am writing in the way you said

Answer (score 0):

Class N has to manage the number of elements in a list somehow.  The usual approaches are to make a public function which returns the number of elements in the array, or to provide an iterator function which loops over all the list's elements.

---

An array with N elements are stored at array[0] through array[N-1].  You're accessing one past the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

> theList would be pointing at the 1st
>   element of the array? Given that the
>   size of array is known, can I loop
>   through with index i and say V *oneV =
>   *vList[i]?

Yes, that is correct.

> I'm guessing that might be the reason
>   why I am getting seg fault or bus
>   error. Could it be the case?

Yes, if you have an invalid pointer and try to dereference it you'll get a segfault.

> WHY did I 'loose' the object at the
>   other end of a pointer? What did I do
>   wrong?

That is difficult to predict without seeing the actual code. Most probable causes are that either you are not filling the `V**` correctly or after putting a V* pointer inside `V**` array you are deleting that object from some other place. BTW, I am assuming that you are allocating memory using `new`, is this assumption correct?

Comment: Yes, I am using new. By "know the size" you mean NOT just in some variables?

Comment: Sorry I misread the question, I read it as Given the size of the array is NOT known..., if you know the size then it is fine.

Answer (score 0):

First rule out the initial ones:

- you are initializing correctly (new instead of automatic/local variables)
- you are accessing the elements correctly (not like in the typo you posted in the question - based on your comment)
- you are using the right size

If you go through all the normal ones and everything is k, then make sure to pay special attention to your loops / size calculations / and anything else that could be causing you to write to unintended addresses.

It is possible to write garbage at unintended locations & then get the error in unexpected places ... the worst I saw like that, was some file descriptors's variables being corrupted because of an array gone wrong right before those variables - it broke on file related functions, which seemed v. crazy.